# How to change SQL to avoid subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is simplified version of queryie I'm working at:

```
SELECT 
    r.id,
    r.nr,

    MAX(CASE WHEN (rm.meta_key = 'supplier_id') THEN (SELECT suppliers.title FROM suppliers WHERE suppliers.id = rm.meta_value) ELSE NULL END) AS supplier,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rm.meta_key = 'client_id') THEN (SELECT clients.name FROM clients WHERE clients.id = rm.meta_value) ELSE NULL END) AS client,

FROM `registries` AS r 
INNER JOIN `registries_meta` AS rm ON `r`.`id` = `rm`.`registries_id`
GROUP BY r.id
LIMIT 100
```

Is it possible to avoid subquery here? I need to tell Mysql "Join registries_metas and if meta_key is client_id JOIN clients.id = meta_value and select clients.name".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the logic you want uses just `join`:

```
SELECT r.id, r.nr,
       c.name as client_name, s.title as supplier
FROM registries r INNER JOIN
     registries_meta rm
     ON r.id = rm.registries_id LEFT JOIN
     clients c 
     ON rm.meta_value = c.id AND rm.meta_key = 'client_id' LEFT JOIN
     suppliers s 
     ON rm.meta_value = s.id AND rm.meta_key = 'supplier_id';
```

If you can have multiple clients/suppliers, you probably want all of them on one row.  That suggests aggregation:

```
SELECT r.id, r.nr,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) as client_names,
       GROUP_CONCAT(s.title) as suppliers
FROM registries r INNER JOIN
     registries_meta rm
     ON r.id = rm.registries_id LEFT JOIN
     clients c 
     ON rm.meta_value = c.id AND rm.meta_key = 'client_id' LEFT JOIN
     suppliers s 
     ON rm.meta_value = s.id AND rm.meta_key = 'supplier_id'
GROUP BY r.id, r.nr;
```

Comment: Almost there, but I need to group rezults by r.id if I do that, nor results will be shown on client_names and suplliers. By the way all relations is one to one.

Comment: I guess I need somehow do MAX() here. As some results will be really empty.

Comment: @RomkaLTU . . . If the relations are 1-1, then the first query will work.  You don't need `MAX()`.  The `LEFT JOIN` takes care of the registries with no suppliers or clients.

Answer (score 1):

do left join with clients and suppliers  table

```
SELECT 
    r.id,
    r.nr,
    c.name AS client_name,s.title as supplier
FROM `registries` AS r 
INNER JOIN `registries_meta` AS rm ON `r`.`id` = `rm`.`registries_id`
left join clients c on rm.meta_value=c.id 
left join suppliers s on rm.meta_value=suppliers.id
```

Comment: No sir, as I said this is simplified version, I also have supplier_id which belongs to suppliers.

Comment: @RomkaLTU where is your supplier table i have not found

Answer (score 1):

Try left joining to the `clients` table.  My intuition tells me that we need to do the pivot in a subquery to find the correct meta value for each key.  Then, we can left join to `clients` using that meta value (which should be the client ID).

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.nr,
    t.client AS client_id,
    COALESCE(c.name, '') AS client_name,
    t.supplier AS supplier_id,
    COALESCE(s.title, '') AS supplier_title
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        r.id,
        r.nr,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rm.meta_key = 'client_id' THEN rm.meta_value END) AS client,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rm.meta_key = 'supplier_id' THEN rm.meta_value END) AS supplier
    FROM registries AS r 
    INNER JOIN registries_meta AS rm
        ON r.id = rm.registries_id
    GROUP BY r.id
) t
LEFT JOIN clients AS c
    ON t.client = c.id
LEFT JOIN suppliers AS s
    ON t.supplier = s.id;
```